# There's clipping on the left side of my radio buttons in Chrome

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome

When in Chrome or Safari on OSX, radio buttons sometimes get clipped one pixel on the left.

[image]

Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This occurs when a radio button with `margin-left: 0;` is wrapped by a container with `overflow: hidden;`. You can see an example [here](http://codepen.io/mattdrose/pen/mKanB?editors=110).

This has only been reproduced in webkit/blink browsers on Mac OSX 10.9.*

[I've opened a ticket with Chromium.](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=396726)

Until fixed in stable, you can hack a fix by using:

```
input[type="radio"] {
  margin-left: 0.5px;
}
```

Comment: I am also facing the same on iPad. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a box-shadow on my inputs which caused that too. If you have a box-shadow take it off with this in your css:

```
input[type=radio]{
 box-shadow: none
```

}